# Encrypted Id is not retaining back in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am encrypting id to hide the raw id in query string and passing it to the controller. But the Id is not retaining back in the postback to  the controller.

for eg

```
/Vendor/EditVendor/mELirpUhRYksFj7k8-XBcQ%3d%3d
```

`DecryptLong()` method will decrypt the above id string `mELirpUhRYksFj7k8-XBcQ%3d%3d` to `1`

controller

```
public ActionResult EditVendor(string id)
    {
        var vendor = _vendorService.GetVendorById(id.DecryptLong());

        return View(vendor);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditVendor(Vendor vendor)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            vendor.Id -- it is always zero and not retaining back
            _vendorService.EditVendor(vendor);    
        }

        return View(vendor);
    }
```

In view

```
@model Eclatech.KidsHub.Objects.Vendor

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditVendor";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit Vendor</h2>

@using(Html.BeginForm("EditVendor","Vendor",FormMethod.Post, new Dictionary<string, object>
                                                             {
                                                                 {"class","form-horizontal"},
                                                                 {"role","form"}
                                                             }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.VendorName, new Dictionary<string, object>
                                          {
                                              {"class","col-sm-2 control-label"}
                                          })
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VendorName,new Dictionary<string, object>
                                               {
                                                   {"class","form-control"}
                                               })
    </div>
</div>

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-default" value="Save" />
}
```

Model

```
public class Vendor : AuditableEntity<long>
{
    public string VendorName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AuditableEntity<T> : Entity<T>, IAuditableEntity
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(256)]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(256)]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Entity<T> : BaseEntity, IEntity<T>
{

    private static long _rowNumber;

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual T Id { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual long RowNumber
    {
        get { return ++_rowNumber; }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's not obvious from the code posted.  Add the `model` definition and perhaps more of the view.

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt, Added model and view

Comment: Check the html rendered by `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)` I suspect it will be `<input ... value="mELirpUhRYksFj7k8-XBcQ%3d%3d" >`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes the value is encrypted string

Comment: Which when posted back wont bind to `int` so `ID` is the default which is `0`. Change your methods parameter name to something else (not the same as one of your model property names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your parameter name for the `EditVendor` method is named `id` and you are returning a model that also has a property named `id`. When you call the `EditVendor` method, the value of the parameter is added to `ModelState` which overrides the value of property `Vendor.Id`. If you inspect the html generated by `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)` you will see that the value of the input is `mELirpUhRYksFj7k8-XBcQ%3d%3d`, not the value returned by `DecryptLong()`. When this posts back, it cannot be bound to type `int` so Id has its default value of zero.

You can test this by adding `ModelState.Clear();` before calling `GetVendorById()`. This will clear the value of `Id` and the hidden inputs value will now be 1. To solve the problem, change the name of the parameter, for example

```
public ActionResult EditVendor(string vendorID)
{
  var vendor = _vendorService.GetVendorById(vendorID.DecryptLong());
  return View(vendor);
}
```